# PyQt - Auto Completer with QLineEdit multiple times

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcompleter

I want to have the possibility to use multiple times the auto completer in my `QLineEdit`, I found example using `QTextEdit` but I can't find for `QLineEdit`. here is a piece of code I use (very simple one) :

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

def main():    
    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    edit    = QLineEdit()
    strList = ["Germany", "Spain", "France", "Norway"]
    completer = QCompleter(strList,edit)

    edit.setCompleter(completer)
    edit.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For example, I want the completer to "start predicting" again the words in the same `QLineEdit` if I add a comma.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer if it can help others, I created a class for Completer :

```
class Completer(QtWidgets.QCompleter):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Completer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.setCompletionMode(QtWidgets.QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        self.setWrapAround(False)

    # Add texts instead of replace
    def pathFromIndex(self, index):
        path = QtWidgets.QCompleter.pathFromIndex(self, index)

        lst = str(self.widget().text()).split(',')

        if len(lst) > 1:
            path = '%s, %s' % (','.join(lst[:-1]), path)

        return path

    # Add operator to separate between texts
    def splitPath(self, path):
        path = str(path.split(',')[-1]).lstrip(' ')
        return [path]
```

And I use it within a class for QLineEdit like :

```
class TextEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setPlaceholderText("example : ")
        self._completer = Completer(self)
        self.setCompleter(self._completer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for PyQt4:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Completer(QtGui.QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Completer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.setCompletionMode(QtGui.QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        self.setWrapAround(False)

    # Add texts instead of replace
    def pathFromIndex(self, index):
        path = QtGui.QCompleter.pathFromIndex(self, index)
        lst = str(self.widget().text()).split(',')
        if len(lst) > 1:
            path = '%s, %s' % (','.join(lst[:-1]), path)
        return path

    def splitPath(self, path):
        path = str(path.split(',')[-1]).lstrip(' ')
        return [path]

class TextEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        words = ["alpha", "omega", "omicron", "zeta"]
        self.setPlaceholderText("example : ")
        self._completer = Completer(words, self)
        self.setCompleter(self._completer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TextEdit()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found might be helpful to someone:

```
class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LineEdit,self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)
        self.multipleCompleter = None

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        QLineEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
        if not self.multipleCompleter:
            return
        c = self.multipleCompleter
        if self.text() == "":
            return
        c.setCompletionPrefix(self.cursorWord(self.text()))
        if len(c.completionPrefix()) < 1:
            c.popup().hide()
            return
        c.complete()

    def cursorWord(self, sentence):
        p = sentence.rfind(" ")
        if p == -1:
            return sentence
        return sentence[p + 1:]

    def insertCompletion(self, text):
        p = self.text().rfind(" ")
        if p == -1:
            self.setText(text)
        else:
            self.setText(self.text()[:p+1]+ text)

    def setMultipleCompleter(self, completer):
        self.multipleCompleter = completer
        self.multipleCompleter.setWidget(self)
        completer.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LineEdit()
    completer = QCompleter(["Animals", "Dogs", "Birds", "Cats", "Elephant", "Zebra"])
    completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    w.setMultipleCompleter(completer)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO maybe you can explain your code a bit. That way people who are not familiar with python can also understand the code.